# Using group_by_hour_of_day: rails using groupdate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I wanted to group the total checkin in a day using the groupdate gem with this code.

```
from = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day
to   = Time.zone.now.end_of_day

customer_checkins = CustomerCheckin.where(created_at: from..to, account_id: 139)

hours = customer_checkins.group_by_hour_of_day(:created_at).count
```

The result is weird because all counts are tagged into hour 0 instead of being tagged to its specific hour of day. The result is shown below.

> {0=>677,  1=>0,  2=>0,  3=>0,  4=>0,  5=>0,  6=>0,  7=>0,  8=>0, 
>   9=>4,  10=>0,  11=>0,  12=>0,  13=>0,  14=>0,  15=>0,  16=>0,  17=>0, 
>   18=>0,  19=>0,  20=>0,  21=>0,  22=>0, 23=>0}

What could be the problem with this one?

Comment: I don't know that specific gem, but I would start by trying without the gem.  What happens if you run `CustomerCheckin.where(created_at: from..to, account_id: 139).select("date_part('hour', created_at)").group("date_part('hour', created_at)").count`?  (This assumes you're using Postgres, but most DBs have a similar method to `date_part`.)

Comment: This is the result of the query given: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: FUNCTION dayabse.date_part does not exist

Comment: Right... like I said, my example above is for _Postgres_.  MySQL has a similar function called `EXTRACT`, e.g. `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at)`.

Comment: Not working. It seems the grouping via extracting the hour of created_at results in a syntax error.

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code in `rails c`.The console will pop up your sql query,so it may help you to  find out the problem.

I guess `group_by_hour_of_day` is your `CustomerCheckin` model function.I don't now whether this function has trim your `:created_at` format. By default the `:created_at` will contain the second like "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",so the sql will group by base on the `second` not the `hour`. You may try to trim the `:created_at` format. Like

```
DateTime.parse("2015-05-08 02:30:01 +0800").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")
=> "2015-05-08 02"
```

Hope it will help you.